# rsync to a Windows share

Tags: permissions, samba, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to sync files from a linux machine to an SMB share (Windows).
However, a weird thing happens, is everytime the `rsync` runs, it syncs the folder names which weren't even touched.
File-wise, all is good.

```
rsync -avzh  --exclude /Something . /mnt/smb-mnt/
```

And the verbose:

```
15:12:37 sending incremental file list
15:12:37 ./
15:12:52 SomeFolderThatWasntChanged/
15:12:57 SomeFolderThatWasntChangedfooter/
15:12:58 SomeFolderThatWasntChanged/mobile/
15:13:01 SomeFolderThatWasntChanged/sideBar/
15:13:01 USdialog/
15:13:02 css/
15:13:04 post/
15:13:05 post/images/
...
```

In my opinion, each time files are moved to the share, the owner and group changes since it's a Windows NTFS permissions.
Is that the reason? And is there a way to avoid checking the owner\group change?

Comment: Are you sure it's "syncing", and not just checking the directory to see if anything has changed?

Comment: @waltinator actually no, I'm not sure, but it takes some time!

Comment: It does have to compare files. You show about 28 sec which seems ok with lots of files to compare.  But if syncing from Linux to NTFS you lose all ownership & permissions. If just data, you can easily reset to a default like you have in /home, but if system files, just about impossible to correctly reset permissions & ownership.